# Como actualizar una fila en SQLite con update()?

Tags: android

Estoy creando una app donde se registran donantes de sangre en una tabla SQLite con varias columnas que reciben los datos, nombre, apellido, edad, etc.y se muestran en un RecyclerView personalizado.

Estos datos se deben poder actualizar mediante un dialogo personalizado, estoy intentando con update(TABLA, values, where, args).

Por ejemplo cambio el nombre lo actualiza pero los demas items aparecen en blanco o cambio el apellido y pasa lo mismo, asi con todos los items de la lista.

El codigo donde intento actualizar los registros

```
// Listener del boton guardar en RecyclerAdapter recibe la posicion
// Aca tambien se llama al dialogo para editar los items
 @Override
public void actualizarRegistro(int posicion) {
    showDialogoEditarDonante();
    this.dPosicion = posicion;

}

//Listener del dialogo recibe los datos ingresados para actualizar
@Override
public void onClickEditListener(String nombDonante, String apellidoDonante,
                                String edad, String peso, String estatura, String tipoDonante, String rhDonante) {

    this.nDNombre = nombDonante;
    this.nDApellido = apellidoDonante;
    this.nDEdad = edad;
    this.nDPeso = peso;
    this.nDEstatura = estatura;
    this.nDTipo = tipoDonante;
    this.nDRh = rhDonante;

    Donantes donantes = listDonantes.get(dPosicion);
    int ident = donantes.getDonanteID();
    Cursor cursor;
    baseDeDatos = new BaseDeDatos(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sq = baseDeDatos.getWritableDatabase();
    String tabla = EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.TABLE_DONANTES;
    String column = EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_ID;
    String[] selectargs = {String.valueOf(ident)};

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_NOMBRE, nDNombre);
    values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_APELLIDO, nDApellido);
    values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_EDAD, nDEdad);
    values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_PESO, nDPeso);
    values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_ESTATURA, nDEstatura);
    values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_TIPO, nDTipo);
    values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_RH, nDRh);

    int result = sq.update(tabla, values, column + " =?", selectargs);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Actualizado registro: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    recuperarDatos();

    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

El metodo para actualizar

```
private void recuperarDatos() {
    DataBaseAdapter db = new DataBaseAdapter(this);

    db.abrirBD();

    if (listDonantes != null) {
        listDonantes.clear();
    }

    Cursor cursor = db.obtenerDonantes();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_ID));
        String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_NOMBRE));
        String apellido = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_APELLIDO));
        String edad = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_EDAD));
        String peso = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_PESO));
        String estatura = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_ESTATURA));
        String tipo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_TIPO));
        String rh = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_RH));

        Donantes donantes = new Donantes(id, nombre, apellido, edad, estatura, peso, tipo, rh);
        listDonantes.add(donantes);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base de prueba y error encontré la solución, el código quedo así:

```
 //Listener obtiene los datos del dialogoEditarDonantes
@Override
public void onClickEditListener(String nombDonante, String apellidoDonante,
                                String edad, String peso, String estatura, String tipoDonante, String rhDonante) {

    this.nDNombre = nombDonante;
    this.nDApellido = apellidoDonante;
    this.nDEdad = edad;
    this.nDPeso = peso;
    this.nDEstatura = estatura;
    this.nDTipo = tipoDonante;
    this.nDRh = rhDonante;

    Donantes donantes = listDonantes.get(dPosicion);
    int ident = donantes.getDonanteID();
    baseDeDatos = new BaseDeDatos(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sq = baseDeDatos.getWritableDatabase();

    String tabla = EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.TABLE_DONANTES;
    String column = EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_ID;
    String[] selectargs = {String.valueOf(ident)};

    if (!nDNombre.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_NOMBRE, nDNombre);
        result = sq.update(tabla, values, column + " =?", selectargs);

    } else if (!nDApellido.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_APELLIDO, nDApellido);
        result = sq.update(tabla, values, column + " =?", selectargs);

    } else if (!nDEdad.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_EDAD, nDEdad);
        result = sq.update(tabla, values, column + " =?", selectargs);

    } else if (!nDPeso.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_PESO, nDPeso);
        result = sq.update(tabla, values, column + " =?", selectargs);

    } else if (!nDEstatura.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_ESTATURA, nDEstatura);
        result = sq.update(tabla, values, column + " =?", selectargs);

    } else if (!nDTipo.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_TIPO, nDTipo);
        result = sq.update(tabla, values, column + " =?", selectargs);

    } else if (!nDRh.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EstructuraDB.EstructuraBase.COLUMN_DONANTE_RH, nDRh);
        result = sq.update(tabla, values, column + " =?", selectargs);

    }
    if (result == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Registro actualizado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sq.close();
        recuperarDatos();
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error no se pudo actualizar el registro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Espero esta solución le sirva a alguien.